# Some Designing issues into the developing a WCF based system

Tags: c#, wcf

Please follow the below given Solution Structure.

[image]

Here I have main three projects under a single solution:
ServiceClient (it is a console application. Consume the SQLMonitorServer WCF Service)

SQLMonitorEngine (This is the core engine which is written into the C# and it helps me to return performance data of configured sql instance.)

SQLMonitorServe (This is a wcf Service, which uses the SQLMonitorEngine and retrive the data from Engine and pass that data to ServiceClient as per request).

**SQLMonitorEngine has below given Class** 
[image]

But here I cant expose this class into the my ServerClient. So I have writtent this class again into the SQLMonitorServer as below given,

[image]

See the interface and exposed service methods into the SQLMonitorServe as here below given,

[image]

And Into the ServerClient I have accessed this service as,

[image]

Now issues are:

1. Why here properties names are _BackingField.? Can't I used it as normal name eg, AuthType directly.?
2. Due to duplicate class of ServerInfo into the SQLMonitorServer and SQLMonitorEngine, my solution is not going to debug and gives me below error,

```html
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SQLMonitorServer.ServerInfo' to 'SQLMonitorEngine.ServerInfo'  D:\Dev\SQLMonitor\SQLMonitorEngine\SQLMonitorServer\SQLMonitorService.svc.cs    17  46  SQLMonitorServer
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'SQLMonitorEngine.QueryAPI.GetServerVersion(SQLMonitorEngine.ServerInfo)' has some invalid arguments   D:\Dev\SQLMonitor\SQLMonitorEngine\SQLMonitorServer\SQLMonitorService.svc.cs    17  20  SQLMonitorServer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ServerInfo` class needs to have auto-properties, not fields. As it has fields, you got fields created by your wcf client wizard.

Your two `ServerInfo` classes are not the same type, so you will need to create a new one of one type and fill the properties with those you want to take from the old type.

Comment: First issue is solved. 
But I didnt get your about second issue. Here the problem is, SQLMoniterEngine also has the same class. And my WCF service call a method of SQLMonitorEngine are retrieve the data. Here This method has an parameter, SQLServerInfo. How I can create this SQLServerInfo at my client,server and Engine?? I am very confused here.

Comment: Maybe you should rename one of your classes. This will clear up the confusion.

Comment: More clear idea,
ServiceClient, 
ServerInfo s  = new ServerInfo(){ type = SQLType, user ="sa", .. };
Console.WriteLine(MonitorServiceClient.GetVersionNumber(s));
On WCF Server,
public object GetSQLVersionNumber(ServerInfo1 serverInfo)
        {
            return QueryAPI.GetServerVersion(serverInfo);
        }
Here ServerInfo is defined at serverSide,
I have already a Class Library, SQLMonitorEngine,
Here a method is defined 
public static object GetServerVersion(ServerInfo serverInfo)
        {
            return SQLHelper.ExecuteScalar("SELECT @@version", serverInfo);
        }

Comment: If I rename any class, then it give me mitchmatched type error.

Comment: If you rename one of the two classes, you should get the very same error you get now (with the new class name in the error message of course). If that's not the case, something is seriously wrong. If you want to keep both classes, you need to find a way to convert one into the other. You cannot pass them where you should pass the other. It's two different types.

Comment: Yeah,, That's why I am confused into this issue. 
IF you have any suggestion for updating this structure, then please suggest.

Comment: The easiest way would be to create two functions, one each for converting your two objects into the other type. If I had to guess, I'd say you only need to set all properties according to the other classes properties. Or You could use AutoMapper. But for one simple class, that would be too much.

Comment: Thanks man.,
Now I have written a method which convert the one object into the other. And it works....